# F#: Filter items found in one list from another list

Tags: f#

Say I have two lists:

```
let a = [1 .. 1000]
let b = [250 .. 500]
```

How do I get a new list that contains the values {1-249, 501-1000}?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since your list is sorted, you can solve this in linear time using this (non-tail recursive) function:

```
let rec except a b =
    match (a, b) with
    | [], x | x, [] -> x
    | x::xs, y::ys ->
        if x < y then x :: except xs (y::ys)
        elif x > y then y :: except (x::xs) ys
        else except xs ys
```

Tail-recursive version:

```
let rec except_tail_recursive a b =
    let rec loop acc a b =
        match (a, b) with
        | [], x | x, [] -> (List.rev acc) @ x
        | x::xs, y::ys ->
            if x < y then loop (x::acc) xs (y::ys)
            elif x > y then loop (y::acc) (x::xs) ys
            else loop acc xs ys
    loop [] a b
```

Comment: Just to make a note on my own function: except [1;2;2;3;4;5] [2;3] returns [1; 2; 4; 5] rather than <code>[1;4;5]. Function assumes you're items are sorted and do not contain duplicates.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know you could reuse a variable name in a match " | [], x | x, [] -> (List.rev acc) @ x" you use x in two different cases.  Neat!

Comment: Also, `except [1; 5] [3]` returns `[1; 3; 5]`; the non-tail-recursive version should be changed to: `elif x > y then except (x::xs) ys` and the tail-recursive version should be changed to: `elif x > y then loop acc (x::xs) ys`

Answer (score 8):

If you want a pure F# solution, your options will vary based on your requirements.  If your lists don't contain duplicated items and you don't care about the order of your output, you can just do:

```
(Set.of_list a) - (Set.of_list b) |> Set.to_list
```

If you know that your items are sorted, this should work and be efficient:

```
let exclude =
  let rec exclude = function
    | [],_ -> [] 
    | a,[] -> a
    | (x::xs as l),(y::ys as r) -> 
        if x < y then x :: (exclude (xs, r))
        elif x > y then exclude (l, ys)
        else exclude (xs, ys)
  fun a b -> exclude (a,b)
```

If you have two lists which may contain duplicates, aren't necessarily sorted, you want results in the order they occured in `a`, and you don't care about performance, you can do:

```
a |> List.filter (fun x -> not (List.contains x b))
```

Comment: I like the set solution, but your filter solution doesn't return the right results. For example, if a = [1] and b = [-1 .. 100], it outputs an empty list. Additionally, if a = [1;2;3;4;5] and b = [-2; -1; 0; 1; 2], then the function returns [3;4;5], which isn't correct either.

Comment: @Juliet: Hmm... those are exactly the results I would expect... Your solution actually gives the symmetric difference, rather than the set difference. I suppose it's ambiguous from the statement of the problem which behavior is desired...

Comment: I can't get the `(Set.ofList a) - `... to compile

Comment: @Maslow - Do you have lists `a` and `b` already defined (as in the original question)?  It still works for me in the Visual Studio 11 Beta (using `Set.ofList` and `Set.toList`, which are the modern names for what used to be `Set.of_list` and `Set.to_list`).

Answer (score 5):

If you're working against the 3.5 framework or higher you could do the following

```
let c = System.Linq.Enumerable.Except(a,b)
```

It's not a pure F# solution but it gets the job done.  The return will be an instance of `IEnumerable<int>` though and not an F# list.