# Get a list of invalid drive letters

Tags: f#, sequences

```
let private GetDrives = seq{
let all=System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives()
for d in all do
    //if(d.IsReady && d.DriveType=System.IO.DriveType.Fixed) then
        yield d
}

let valid={'A'..'Z'}
let rec SearchRegistryForInvalidDrive (start:RegistryKey) = seq{
    let validDrives=GetDrives |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.Name.Substring(0,1))
    let invalidDrives= Seq.toList validDrives |> List.filter(fun x-> not (List.exists2 x b)) //(List.exists is the wrong method I think, but it doesn't compile
```

I followed [F#: Filter items found in one list from another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506280/f-filter-items-found-in-one-list-from-another-list) but could not apply it to my problem as both the solutions I see don't seem to compile. List.Contains doesn't exist (missing a reference?) and ListA - ListB doesn't compile either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
open System.IO
let driveLetters = set [ for d in DriveInfo.GetDrives() -> d.Name.[0] ]
let unused = set ['A'..'Z'] - driveLetters
```

Comment: so you can subtract sets, but not sequences? what's the closest thing to a set in c#?

Comment: @Maslow : `System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<>`, and LINQ has many set-like operations.

Comment: In C# you could do: `var unused = new HashSet<char>(allLetters); unused.ExceptWith(driveLetters);`

Answer (score 3):

Your first error is mixing between `char` and `string`, it is good to start with `char`:

```
let all = {'A'..'Z'}
let validDrives = GetDrives |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.Name.[0])
```

Now invalid drive letters are those letters which are in `all` but not in `validDrives`:

```
let invalidDrives = 
      all |> Seq.filter (fun c -> validDrives |> List.forall ((<>) c))
```

Since `validDrives` is traversed many times to check for membership, turning it to a set is better in this example:

```
let all = {'A'..'Z'}
let validDrives = GetDrives |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.Name.[0]) |> Set.ofSeq
let invalidDrives = all |> Seq.filter (not << validDrives.Contains)
```