# Fastest way to reduce a list based on another list using F#

Tags: f#

What would be the most efficient way in F# to remove items in one list based on items in another list?

example:
`seq1 = ["blue"; "green"; "red"; "green" ...]`
          `seq2 = ["soda"; "green"; "pop" ...]`

seq1 has 50,000 items initially
seq2 has 12 and continues to grow in size over time

What I want to do is remove ALL instances of seq1 if that value is in seq2

I have the following code which is as slow as I can make it - not what I want.

```
let result = seq1 |> Seq.filter(fun a -> (Seq.exists(fun name -> name = a) seq2) = false)
```

I am trying to find the fasted way to do this functionally (no loops, etc)

Thanks :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [F#: Filter items found in one list from another list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506280/f-filter-items-found-in-one-list-from-another-list)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `seq1` is relatively long and `seq2` is relatively short, then you can create a set from the elements of `seq2` and then use the `Contains` method of the set to check if it contains the specified element. Lookup in a set is much faster than lookup in a sequence using `Seq.exists`.

I was testing this using a simple script based on your numbers:

```
#time
let seq1 = Array.init 50000 (fun i -> ["blue"; "green"; "red"].[i%3])
let seq2 = Array.init 12 (fun i -> [ "soda"; "green"; "pop"].[i%3])
```

Now, here are a few options (I wrap them in `for i in 1 .. 10 do` to get more reasonable numbers and then divided this by 10):

```
// 15ms - this is the original version, but I added `Array.ofSeq` to materialize it
let result = seq1 |> Seq.filter(fun a -> 
   (Seq.exists(fun name -> name = a) seq2) = false) |> Array.ofSeq

// 12ms - this is using `Array.filter` directly, which turns out to be as slow
let result = seq1 |> Array.filter(fun a -> 
  (Seq.exists(fun name -> name = a) seq2) = false) 

// 2ms - using `set.Contains` is much faster, even when we create the set each time
let l = set seq2
let result = seq1 |> Array.filter(fun a -> l.Contains a = false)
```

Note that I did not push the `set seq2` call out of the loop - if you do that, it is even faster (you only need to create the set when changing `seq2` and then you can keep it).

Comment: Good answer, but you can write that last expression `let result = seq1 |> Array.filter l.Contains` ;p

Comment: @markseemann I think you'd need `l.Contains >> not`, but that's still nice and not overusing the point free style!

Comment: @Tomas thank you very much Tomas, what a difference that made.  :-)